# Read data from Shortcut

Tags: android, android-intent, android-shortcut, android-shortcutmanager

I am creating multiple shortcuts of an Activity in my application by using this code

```
Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleChat.class);
shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);                       
shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);                      

Bitmap bm =  ((BitmapDrawable)contact_image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();       
Bitmap bti = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 120, 120, false);                  

Intent addIntent = new Intent();                                              
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);                    
addIntent.putExtra("user_id", csUserId);                   
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, csUserName);      
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON, bti);                          
addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");          
getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
```

Everything is working perfectly fine for shortcut creation but I want to read the data from the shortcut OR

*I want to read this `user_id` whenever that shortcut is clicked*.

I can't put it in `SharedPreferences` as it can be more than one shortcuts each linking to different `user_id`.

I have searched and so far couldn't find anything.

Shortcuts have been improved quite a lot after android 7.0 but I have to make it working for older devices too (say from 4 to onward).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Everything is working perfectly fine for shortcut creation

FWIW, I don't think it will work on Android O.

> I want to read this user_id whenever that shortcut is clicked.

Put it as an extra in `shortcutIntent`.

Comment: It worked perfectly well. Thanks. Also can you please put some light on how it will not work on Android O.

Comment: @SyedaZunairah: "The com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT broadcast no longer has any effect on your app, because it is now a private, implicit broadcast. Instead, you should create an app shortcut by using the requestPinShortcut() method from the ShortcutManager class." (from [the Android O release notes](https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#as)).